# Object Location Change on Blender Python

Tags: python, blender

I was following an animation example with Python in Blender 2.69, by typing a line by line.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.location[2] = 0.0
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=10.0, index=2)
obj.location[2] = 1.0
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=20.0, index=2)
```

But I have encountered an error on the 3rd line, which is saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
```

I am confused because I just followed a simple example.

Why is it saying the object has no attribute 'location'?

I'll be appreciated for your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that the error would be reported after the second line because the variable `obj` has not been set. Most likely this would be from a small typo.

You can verify this by looking at the type of the variable in the python console. When getting the error you will see -

```
>>> type(obj)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

While if it had been set correctly you will get -

```
>>> type(obj)
<class 'bpy_types.Object'>
```